# Automatic refreshing one method continuously

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, refresh

have written a method for updating which will call itself again and again when we start that activity, as mentioned below. I wants to stop this method function once we get an output (Now, it keeps running even if we get output). Please let me know if there is any possibility to do it.

```
-(void)reloadMethod{
[self downloadProgressAudio];
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self reloadMethod];
});
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep calling this method until you get an output, the you need to include that test, and only call the function again if you don't have any output.

```
if !outputDataExists {
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self reloadMethod];
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use timer here

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
        target:self
        selector:@selector(reloadMethod)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:YES];
```

Once you are done with your repeated execution then do this

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

Comment: the whole point of the question was how to recognise that execution should stop - and you have not addressed that point

Comment: You have use 
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
to stop the execution, i.e, it is in your hand when to stop it. Thus, you know when will it stop

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i got it it's working now!